# Simple session example not working

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I writed this little session script and i saw that's not working.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $username = $_SESSION["username"];
?>

  <html><head>
  <title>Simple Session Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  echo "<h3>Hello $username</h3>";
  }

  else {
  echo "<h3>OUT!</h3>"; 
  echo "<form action='index.php' method='POST'>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='username'>";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
  }

  ?>
```

I can't figure out which part is wrong. looks all good for m but definatelly something is wrong.

Comment: You have a logic error. You check if the session value exists but try to use a post variable. They are not related.

Comment: I removed the post variable but still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
      $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    ?>

      <html><head>
      <title>Simple Session Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>

    <?

      if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
      $username = $_POST["username"];
      $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
      echo "<h3>Hello $username</h3>";
      }

else if($username) {
      echo "<h3>Hello $username</h3>";
      }

      else {
      echo "<h3>OUT!</h3>"; 
      echo "<form action='index.php' method='POST'>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='username'>";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
      }

      ?>
```