# How to save form post to session and stay in the same html page?

Tags: php, html, forms, session, post

I have a form in html that post income to incomesave.php where session is initiated and save all the form contents to session.

The problem is that I want to stay in the same page when submitting form all the while saving data to session and use that session values to populate the income history on the same page. How can I stay in the same page and process the data with php?

This is the form inside html:

```
<form action="lib/php/incomesave.php" method="post">
  $: <input type="number" name="price">
  type: <input type="text" name="source" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="title">
        Income history
    </div>

    <div id="incomehistory">
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the incomesave.php to save the form data

```
<?php
session_start();

$price = $_POST['price'];
$source = $_POST['source'];
$_SESSION['price'] = $price;
$_SESSION['source'] = $source;

echo $_SESSION['price']; // print price 
echo $_SESSION['source'];
?>
```

I want to stay on the same page, run the incomesave.php and populate the income history area of the html page with `$_SESSION` data. How can I do that? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By "stay on the same page" do you mean that you want the data posted in the background without ever leaving the page?  Or that you want to be redirected back to the page?  Something else?

Comment: I would like the data to be posted in the background without leaving the page if possible. If not, I dont mind redirecting back to the page.

Comment: To post the data in the background, look into something called AJAX.  There are many examples online that you can reference.  Basically you'd make a request to the server from JavaScript code and the page itself doesn't refresh.

Comment: How can I change part of the html after the ajax post and saving? where would I implement the code?

Comment: When implementing an AJAX call there's usually a "callback" which is invoked after the request completes.  In that callback function is where you'd respond to the AJAX request, by modifying the page in some way or notifying the user of any errors.  Modifying the page is a pretty broad concept here.  Essentially you'd want to identify the HTML elements that you want to change and update their `innerHTML` properties, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Submit a AJAX requet to the server and modify the DOM with the result.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "incomesave.php", false);
xhttp.send();
document.getElementById("incomehistory").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to post the data form without changing the page and after the ajax call, save the data inside incomesave.php and after that, use callback or success method to change the html using `.innerHTML`

thank you to all the comments to lead up to the answer!

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want the page to refresh you have to use ajax to complete this. I'm not gonna post a code example since I don't know how familiar you are with ajax post.
Do a research on ajax posting and result processing. If you are familiar with ajax post, let me know so I can do some code example..

IF you just want to stay on same page, check the answer I posted earlier on sessions

[Simple session example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482589/simple-session-example-not-working/34482650#34482650)

Comment: Yes I am familiar with ajax. after posting with ajax, I can save the data. How do I update the income history part?

Comment: On the incomesave.php collect all the POST data using $return = $_POST; and then echo it with json_encode: echo json_encode($return);
After that you can collect it as data in ajax success method and append html of your start page

Answer (score -2):

if you set form action it will redirect you to action url page. On that page you initialize all session data and then redirect it to same page using header like

```
header('URL');
```

url will be html page url.